# Use the same _Id in two models with backbone and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, backbone.js, express

I have two models 'User' and 'point'.
i need when i create a user, with an id like 2juifdsf7tdf65sd67, the same id go to 'point' model.
 An ID for the two models sometime.
Its possible?
 how to do this in an alternative method?

Update: 
when i create the 'User', i need him to get an 'point', the model 'point' get the same id of the user, all in a html view page. but when a create a new user and a point, the id is different, is not the same.

Comment: Hm, your question is pretty unclear, so whats stops you to create these models in mongo with any IDs you like and parse it on client side?

Comment: um, maybe its clear, when i create the 'User', i need him to get an 'point', the model 'point' get the same id of the user, all in a html view page. but when a create a new user and a point, the id is different, is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put User and Point in 2 different collection you can use same id for those and of couse you should set _id manually

```
db.User.insert(
{
    _id : 100,
    ...
})

db.Point.insert(
{
    _id : 100,
    ...
})
```

_id could be number, string and ...
But I think the better solution for u is using reference id

```
db.User.insert(
{
    _id : 100,
    point_Id: 13588,
    ...
})
db.Point.insert(
{
    _id : 13588,
    ...
})
```

Comment: thanks, i will try, but, how to reference this in a webview? like in an node server, express, sails , etc.. ?